# Is there a way I can check dates (going over 2 years back) on Steam Store purchases?

Tags: steam

Is there a way to check the date I bought games on my Steam library? I bought Garry's Mod sometime back in 2012 and I want to see the exact date (day, month, year). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There may be a limit on how far it goes, but my Steam transaction history goes back to December 2009.

To view your own transaction history from the Steam client, click on your account balance in the upper right of the client to bring up the account page. Then select "STORE TRANSACTIONS" and then "SEE ALL" at the bottom recent transaction list.

[image: Steam Transaction History screenshot]

If you have no account balance, you can also view your history by going to the "Steam" menu in the top left, selecting "Settings", clicking "View Account Details", and then clicking "Purchase History".

Comment: I have 673 items dating back to 2010 so it seems to show everything.

Comment: please mark your question as solved when this answer helped you

Answer (score 20):

The alternative way is to click steam support and click the game that you want to know the purchase date. Then, look at the top right corner, which will show the purchase date of the game. It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: This is a good solution because it lets you see purchase dates for games to old for your account purchase history. For example, my account purchase history goes back as far as 2006, but I have games bought in 2005 whose date can be viewed with this method.

Comment: this also works for games you redeemed through a code which won't show up in your purchase history

Comment: And it also still works even in early 20´23.  So, this is the *BEST* answer (it's also faster than scrolling through your whole purchase history).

Answer (score 1):

You can also just navigate to your game library and see the date each game was purchased (right beside "Install"):

[image]

Comment: This appears to only work if the game hasn't been played in the last year or so. Otherwise it will tell you when you lasted played it instead.

Comment: @RossRidge Good point, I've just notice that actually. But hopefully this method works for mugen's purposes.

Comment: This is also not true anymore _at all_.  UIs get changed all the time these days.